# Windows Phone: re-layout after software keyboard is shown

Tags: c++, windows-phone

When the software keyboard is shown, it occludes part of the page UI. That is undesirable. Is there a way to automatically update the UI layout just like Android Activity's onConfigurationChanged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that one needs to register handler to update the layout:

```
auto inputpane = InputPane::GetForCurrentView();
inputpane->Showing += ref new TypedEventHandler<InputPane^, InputPaneVisibilityEventArgs^>(this, &MainPage::OnInputPaneVisibilityChanged);
inputpane->Hiding += ref new TypedEventHandler<InputPane^, InputPaneVisibilityEventArgs^>(this, &MainPage::OnInputPaneVisibilityChanged);
```

To handle the event, we can make use of `OccludedRect` in the event argument from which we can extract the height taken by the keyboard. First, we preserve some UI element, say `SpaceForKeyboard`, in the XAML. For example:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0"> <!-- Main UI goes here --> </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="SpaceForKeyboard"> <!-- Dummy grid for the keyboard --> </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Then in the handler, just change the size for the preserved space:

```
void MainPage::OnInputPaneVisibilityChanged(InputPane^ sender, InputPaneVisibilityEventArgs^ args)
{
    SpaceForKeyboard->Height = sender->OccludedRect.Height;
}
```

As simple as it should be, when the keyboard is shown/hidden, the handler is invoked and it sets (or hide) the dummy grid to occupy the space where the keyboard is shown.