# Adapting page layout when keyboard is shown

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

My application has a pivot page, inside one pivot item I have a grid with a list in the top row, and a textbox for filtering in the bottom row.

The problem I have is that when the textbox is selected, the soft keyboard gets shown and 'pushes' everything else up. So the top half of the list is out of view and you can't see half of the filtered results.

Ideally, I'd like just the title of the Pivot/pivot item to be hidden, but the list to be 'squished' (size reduced, not zoomed out) so there are no parts of it outside the viewport.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [`InputPane`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.inputpane.aspx) type and the `Showing` event.

You can either choose to listen to the event and adjust your UI as appropriate (based on the [`OccludedRect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.inputpanevisibilityeventargs.occludedrect.aspx)) or you could set the [`EnsuredFocusedElementInView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.inputpanevisibilityeventargs.ensuredfocusedelementinview.aspx) property to `true` and handle it all yourself.

Comment: Ouch, sounds complicated. Especially as the OccludedRect is in DIPs. I'm going to try it based on the example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27827874/windows-phone-re-layout-after-software-keyboard-is-shown

Comment: The term "DIPS" doesn't really apply here (it has legacy meaning). The value you get back is the exact value you need to use for computing your layout in XAML.